# IntelliJ Gradle fails to build new project

Tags: java, windows, gradle, intellij-idea, build

I have clean installed the latest version on IntelliJ and Gradle, ensuring Gradle is correctly set up in my Windows environment (I can run Gradle and build my project successfully through the command line in Windows and IntelliJ).

My issue arrises when I try to get IntelliJ to update the project when I make changes to my `build.gradle` file (see below). I get the following error and I cannot figure out what's gone wrong. This is a fresh project and fresh install of everything.

Error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Initialization script 'C:\Users\Kris\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit.gradle' line: 41

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating initialization script.
> org/gradle/internal/impldep/com/google/common/collect/Lists

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating initialization script.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$2.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:237)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptTarget.addConfiguration(DefaultScriptTarget.java:74)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:242)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:69)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    ...

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gradle/internal/impldep/com/google/common/collect/Lists
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.internal.ExtraModelBuilder.<init>(ExtraModelBuilder.java:55)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.internal.ExtraModelBuilder.<init>(ExtraModelBuilder.java:49)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    ...


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 104ms
```

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
mainClassName = 'Main'

group 'com.ritcat.cinder'
version '1.0'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': mainClassName
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
}
```

Comment: What do you have selected in Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | **Use Gradle from:**? Make sure the same Gradle is used in IDE as from command line. Try also selecting different option for Gradle distribution there.

Comment: @Andrey Both options (`Build and runusing:` and `Run tests using:`) are set to `Gradle (Default)`. The only other option here is `IntelliJ IDEA` which has the same issue. The Gradle JVM is set to 15.0.1 but changing this also has no effect.

Comment: What versions of Gradle and IntelliJ are you using? Looks like you might have some old ones that are not compatible with each other.

Comment: @BjørnVester Latest 6.7

Comment: Ok, so I have temprarily managed to fix it. By pointing IntelliJ to the local gradle build (it turns out it wasnt using this) it now build. but is the above error a configuration error on my part or a potential IntelliJ Gradle plugin bug?

Comment: Not sure. But in general, strive for using the newest version of IntelliJ if you are not on it already (the latest one at this time is `2020.2.3`). There is a tight integration between the two, and if you fall behind on IntelliJ, it might not work with newer versions of your frameworks.

Comment: This looks like incompatibility between the Gradle version and gradle tooling API which use used by IntelliJ IDEA. I would suggect you to use newer Gradle versions. If you use gradle wrapper - update the version in the wrapper properties: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html